# Transpose of DataFrame not correlating?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working on a CSV containing ratings of different music artists that I am turning into a DataFrame for correlation using pandas.  The problem is, when I transpose the DataFrame and use the `.corr()` function on it, it returns an empty DataFrame and the correlation of the transpose is what I need.  Any ideas why it's doing this? Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
musicRatingsFile = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aportell/machine-learning/master/MusicRatings.csv"
musicRatingsData = pd.read_csv(musicRatingsFile)
df = DataFrame(musicRatingsData)
df2 = df.dropna()
df3 = df2.transpose()
df3.corr()
```

Comment: What is `df3.dtypes`? I suspect they are all objects. You can try `df3.astype('float')` but we need to know more about your dataset first. Can you post a sample?

Comment: Also, verify that `df2 = df.dropna()` is not removing all rows from your DataFrame.

Comment: I edited so that the csv is a link to see.  I checked `df3.types` and they're all objects.  `df2 = df.dropna()` isn't removing all rows.

Answer (score 2):

You have a column that consists of strings (you probably want that column as index) and you also have two columns treated as objects even though they are numbers. You can fix that with:

```
cor = df2.set_index('student').astype('float').T.corr()

cor.head()
Out: 
student             Colton     Bryce  Mikaela Goldrich  Joe Goulet  \
student                                                              
Colton            1.000000 -0.467859         -0.083099   -0.195272   
Bryce            -0.467859  1.000000          0.008893    0.391781   
Mikaela Goldrich -0.083099  0.008893          1.000000    0.341112   
Joe Goulet       -0.195272  0.391781          0.341112    1.000000   
Trevor Martineau  0.174185  0.444854         -0.175762    0.266465
```

`.T` here takes the transpose.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been on this problem for so long.  It worked perfectly!